# EJS Static css files stop working when i pass reference parameter in URL

Tags: ejs

I am using ejs template engine and express js (node js), when i pass the reference parameter in url, static css files stops work

Answer (score 0):

Your reference parameter is separated from the rest of the URL by a path separator character (`/`).

Relative URLs which don't start with a `/` are relative to the current path.

By changing the path, you change where the URL is relative to.

Since you are relative to a different path, your new URL resolves to the wrong place.

Change the `href` of your `link` to the stylesheet so it points to where the stylesheet is. This is most easily achieved by starting it with `/` (e.g. `href="/static/styles/your.css"`).